# can I use KSQL to generate processing-time timeouts?

Tags: apache-flink, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

I am trying to use KSQL to do whatever processing I can within a time limit and get the results at that time limit. See [Timely (and Stateful) Processing with Apache Beam](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/08/28/timely-processing.html) under "Processing Time Timers" for the same idea illustrated using Apache Beam.

Given:

1. A stream of transactions with unique keys;
2. Updates to these transactions in the same stream; and
3. A downstream processor that wants to receive the updated transactions at a specific timeout - say 20 seconds - after the transactions appeared in the first stream.

Conceptually, I was thinking of creating a KTable of the first stream to hold the latest state of the transactions, and using KSQL to create an output stream by querying the KTable for keys with (create_time + timeout) < current_time. (and adding the timeouts as "updates" to the first stream so I could filter those out from the KTable)

I haven't found a way to do this in the KSQL docs, and even if there were a built-in current_time, I'm not sure it would be evaluated until another record came down the stream.

How can I do this in KSQL? Do I need a custom UDF? If it can't be done in KSQL, can I do it in KStreams?

=====

Update: It looks like KStreams does not support this today - Apache Flink appears to be the way to go for this use case (and many others). If you know of a clever way around KStreams' limitations, tell me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the `punctuate()` functionality in the [Processor API](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html) of Kafka Streams, which might be what you are looking for.  You can use punctuate() with stream-time (default: event-time) as well as with processing-time (via `PunctuationType.WALL_CLOCK_TIME`).  Here, you would implement a `Processor` or a `Transformer`, depending on your needs, which will use `punctuate()` for the timeout functionality.

See https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html for more information.

Tip: You can use such a Processor/Transformer also in the DSL of Kafka Streams.  This means you can keep using the more convenient DSL, if you like to, and only need to plug in the Processor/Transformer at the right place in your DSL-based code.

Comment: Thanks! I may attempt this after trying it first with the higher-level abstractions in Flink's API.